# How to Pass JSON in the body of GET Request in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

Trying to pass this JSON in the body of a get request in rest assured. Is creating a JSON object a way to go ?

```
{
    "pharmacyListId": null,
    "pharmacyListName": "PTA",
    "customerSetTypeId": 1,
    "customerId": null,
    "pharmacyId": null,
    "providerAffiliateId": null,
    "providerPlanId": null,
    "providerChain": null,
    "providerNetworkId": null,
    "pharmacyZip": null,
    "pharmacyZipExtension": null,
    "pharmacyStateCode": "MI",
    "fillDate": "2021-01-01",
    "relationshipId": null,
    "organizationId": null,
    "paymentCentreId": null,
    "providerNpi": null,
    "remitReconId": null,
    "countryCode": null,
    "memberState": null,
    "memberZipCode": null,
    "memberZipCodeExtension": null
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? GET request doesn't contain body.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 GET requests MAY contain body. https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/8343843

Comment: If your api works like you said, you have many ways to deal with that, 3 easy-to-maitain ways might be 1. Map 2. POJO 3. JSON object. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string for your json :

```
String Json = "{\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyListId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyListName\": \"PTA\",\n" +
            "    \"customerSetTypeId\": 1,\n" +
            "    \"customerId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"providerAffiliateId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"providerPlanId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"providerChain\": null,\n" +
            "    \"providerNetworkId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyZip\": null,\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyZipExtension\": null,\n" +
            "    \"pharmacyStateCode\": \"MI\",\n" +
            "    \"fillDate\": \"2021-01-01\",\n" +
            "    \"relationshipId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"organizationId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"paymentCentreId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"providerNpi\": null,\n" +
            "    \"remitReconId\": null,\n" +
            "    \"countryCode\": null,\n" +
            "    \"memberState\": null,\n" +
            "    \"memberZipCode\": null,\n" +
            "    \"memberZipCodeExtension\": null\n" +
            "}";
```

and with rest-assured you can have something like that :

```
Response response = given()
                .body(Json)
                .when()
                .get("http://restAdress")
                .then()
                .extract().response();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clarify the case. Despite the standard does not put explicit restriction to sending payload with `GET` request there is a very high probability that your API server or HTTP server that hosts your API code would ignore that payload.

If that is still the case, the simplest way to send your json with RestAssured is:

```java
RestAssured
    .with()
      .proxy("localhost", proxyServer.getPort())
      .body("{\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyListId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyListName\": \"PTA\",\n" +
        "    \"customerSetTypeId\": 1,\n" +
        "    \"customerId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"providerAffiliateId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"providerPlanId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"providerChain\": null,\n" +
        "    \"providerNetworkId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyZip\": null,\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyZipExtension\": null,\n" +
        "    \"pharmacyStateCode\": \"MI\",\n" +
        "    \"fillDate\": \"2021-01-01\",\n" +
        "    \"relationshipId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"organizationId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"paymentCentreId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"providerNpi\": null,\n" +
        "    \"remitReconId\": null,\n" +
        "    \"countryCode\": null,\n" +
        "    \"memberState\": null,\n" +
        "    \"memberZipCode\": null,\n" +
        "    \"memberZipCodeExtension\": null\n" +
        "}\n")
      .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .get("http://YOUR_ENDPOINT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **gson** for clean code

Depedency:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```

Use gson:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

Sample code:

```
JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
body.addProperty("pharmacyListId", (String) null);
body.addProperty("pharmacyListName", "PTA");
body.addProperty("customerSetTypeId", 1);
body.addProperty("customerId", (String) null);
body.addProperty("pharmacyId", (String) null);
body.addProperty("providerAffiliateId", (String) null);
body.addProperty("providerPlanId", (String) null);
body.addProperty("providerChain", (String) null);
```

Output:

```
{
    "pharmacyListId": null,
    "pharmacyListName": "PTA",
    "customerSetTypeId": 1,
    "customerId": null,
    "pharmacyId": null,
    "providerAffiliateId": null,
    "providerPlanId": null,
    "providerChain": null
}
```

I hope this helps.